# Can we run specflow TC's using XUnit in parallel when the Bamboo Job is running

Tags: xunit, specflow, bamboo

I am using Specflow (not **specflow+runner**) and Xunit for writing API Test. A bamboo build pipeline is created to execute all our api TC's. When I am running our TC's via Visual Studio it's taking 15 min to execute(~200 TC's) but when I am running via Bamboo pipeline it's taking 30 min.

All the TC's run inside bamboo pipeline are executed sequentially or we can run them in parallel so that we can reduce the execution time.

Comment: What you you mean by "TC's"?

Comment: You might just need to [configure XUnit to run tests in parallel](https://xunit.net/docs/running-tests-in-parallel).